# i dont know how to solve this it UncaughtClientError > TypeError Uncaught Javascript Error > Cannot read p

Tags: javascript

```
UncaughtClientError > TypeError
Uncaught Javascript Error > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceChildren')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceChildren')
    at Object.confirm (https://bobot-editor.odoo.com/web/assets/b6a4648/website.backend_assets_all_wysiwyg.min.js:3646:552)
    at CodeEditorDialog.onConfirm (https://bobot-editor.odoo.com/web/assets/b6a4648/website.backend_assets_all_wysiwyg.min.js:3644:24)
    at Object.mainEventHandler (https://bobot-editor.odoo.com/web/assets/8a0854f/web.assets_web.min.js:1581:77)
    at HTMLButtonElement.listener (https://bobot-editor.odoo.com/web/assets/8a0854f/web.assets_web.min.js:757:15)
```

i want it to open file exproil

Comment: Please post the code of the JS file in which you are getting this error. Without looking at the code it's not possible to debug the problem.